# Objects disappear at certain angles

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d

So I made a water shader and for some reason in-game, the object disappears at certain camera angles. the material is also flipping the plane 90 degrees when i place it on an object

[ShaderGraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Pxv.png)

[ShaderGraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k73hL.png)

[FlippedPlaneProBuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk47x.png)

[VideoOfError](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZzvwpoDRAc)

I tried changing the alpha but that had no effect

Comment: well, Video is private.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wager that your plane is moving into the near-clip plane of the camera. Anything that is not within the camera's viewable frustum is clipped away (not rendered).

[read more here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html#:%7E:text=.-,Clip%20Planes,-The%20Near%20and)